# Behavior of JVM with Cloneable class

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, cloneable

I know `Cloneable` is a marker interface and using it has pros and cons, but I want to know:

1. What is memory strategy of JVM for `Cloneable` class?

Comment: Define (1) 'memory strategy' and (2) 'integrated memory'.

Comment: 1. java add housekeeping information to reference type in memory and now is there any extra information for cloneable class?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "memory strategy" for cloneable classes, and they don't need more memory than other non-cloneable classes.

---

I am not entirely sure what you mean by "memory strategy" or "integrated memory".   But it is moot, because the JVM treats cloneable classes no different from other classes.

The only thing *different* about cloneable classes is that the `clone()` method uses a *back door* mechanism to create the cloned object that avoids calling constructors in the normal way.  But that has no impact on the way that memory is managed.

---

> 1)  Java adds housekeeping information to reference type in memory.  Is there any extra information for cloneable class?

No.